# Times when inline functioning cannot be used

Tags: c++, function, inline

Im studying inline functions in C++ and have come to a section concerning limitations of its use. It says:

> The compiler also cannot perform
>   inlining if the address of the
>   function is taken implicitly or
>   explicitly.

Can someone explain to me, perhaps with an example of some sort, what exactly this means?

Comment: Oh I hate this new free question downvotes system. What the hell was wrong with this question, people?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what book is making that statement?

Comment: The book is thinking in c++ by Bruce Eckel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two somewhat separate decisions the compiler makes concerning function inlining:

- whether a particular function call is inlined;
- whether a non-inline version of the function exists.

The first is decided by the compiler on a case-by-case basis, if inlining is possible at that point. It won't be possible if the function is virtual, or called through a function pointer, and it can't determine at compile time which function is to be called. It won't be possible if the definition is not available to the compiler, perhaps because it is defined in a different translation unit and the compiler does not do "whole program optimisation". The decision may, or may not, be influenced by whether the function is declared `inline`, and other factors such as its size and how often it is called.

The second depends on whether a non-inline version is required. It will be required if any call to it is not inlined. It will also (as per your quotation) be required if anything needs the address of the function, as then it must have an address. This can happen either directly (for example by assigning the address to a function pointer), or indirectly (for example, virtual functions will need their address stored somewhere to look up at runtime according to the object's dynamic type).

The existence of the non-inline version will not prevent any particular call to the function from being inlined, although it's possible that it might influence the compiler's decision, particularly if it's configured to optimise for code size.

To summarise, your quotation is simplistic and not entirely accurate; the compiler can still "perform inlining" if the address is taken, it just can't omit the non-inline version.

Comment: Thanks, your example of assigning an address to a function pointer really helps understand what this statement means.

Answer (score 6):

You can mark ***any*** function as inline. Even a virtual function, even a recursive function, even a veeery veery long function, even if its address is taken. The main difference between an inline and non-inline function is that the definition of the former must appear in every translation unit (aka source file) in which it is used ( that's why inline functions are usually defined in the .h file), whereas the latter must be defined only once. You can use the inline function in every way that you can use a non-inline one.

The actual inlining part is up to the compiler. It can ignore your request, if, for example, your function is recursive or too long. On the other hand, the compiler may choose to inline a function which you haven't actually marked as inline.

Comment: in the newer versions of GCC, there is an option for whole program optimisation - which AFAIK, will make the requirement to place any code you hope to be inlined in the header, redundant...

Answer (score 4):

It's just wrong: ability to inline a function call is not affected by computing 2+2 or by taking the address of the function somewhere.

Which book or article are you reading?

On the other hand, if the address is taken then it might be practically impossible to remove the separate machine code function.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_c++/Chapter09_009.html

Comment: Oh, "Thinking in C++" by Bruce Eckel. Well, quite a number of errors in that book have surfaced over the years. But as far as I know Bruce has never corrected anything. So, just be careful. He writes some good stuff for novices, but he also writes meaningless and incorrect stuff. As he did here.

Comment: Just when you mention mistakes, in one question in the book it ask you to make a class in a header file that contains a inline function called print. In the book solution however it only has print() declaration in the header and its definition in a sepearate file. Am I right in saying that this is a mistake also and that if I want an inline function in a header file it must include both the definition and declaration for it to be an inline function?

Comment: @Bap: an extern linkage `inline` function must be defined, semantically identically, in *every translation unit* where it's used. Whether that means that the book has an error, I don't know. I do have the book (downloaded in order to answer questions about it) but sorry, I don't have the time to get into it... But in general, it's Bad to just declare an inline function in a header, and not define it there, because then each translation unit that uses the function must get its function definition by other means. Which no-one expects -- it would be like the Spanish Inquisition! Cheers,

Comment: @Alf P The problem I had with declaring and defining the function in the header is that you arent hiding your implementation from a client user, however as im only in the learning stages and not as yet working with this language commercially this isn't something im going to spend any more time worrying about. Thanks for your help, really appreciate the time and effort you put into answering my question.